# Value doesn't change using sess.run() in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got a problem while doing some simple compute, my code is like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
#...
Zeta=0.05
Lambda=2**20

step1 =sess.run(tf.matmul(x_k,alpha_T))
step2 =Lambda*step1
step3 =Zeta+step2
step1_2_3 = sess.run(Zeta + Lambda*tf.matmul(x_k,alpha_T))

print step1
print step2
print step3
print step1_2_3
```

and it print out like:

```
[[ 1.60326695]]
[[ 1681147.25]]
[[ 1681147.3]]
[[ 1681147.25]]
```

It looks like `step1_2_3` is combined of `step1`, `step2`, `step3`.

Why isn't `step1_2_3`: `[[ 1681147.3]]`?

Comment: Please include the definitions of x_k and alpha_T so that this will be a verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()

x_k = np.array([[1.0]])
alpha_T = np.array([[1.60326695]])

Zeta = 0.05
Lambda = 2**20

step1 = sess.run(tf.matmul(x_k,alpha_T))
step2 = Lambda*step1
step3 = Zeta+step2
step1_2_3 = sess.run(Zeta + Lambda*tf.matmul(x_k,alpha_T))

print('step1', step1)
print('step2', step2)
print('step3', step3)
print('step1_2_3', step1_2_3)
```

which produced this:

```
('step1', array([[ 1.60326695]]))
('step2', array([[ 1681147.2453632]]))
('step3', array([[ 1681147.2953632]]))
('step1_2_3', array([[ 1681147.2953632]]))
```

Seems like they're the same for me. Maybe there is something in some code that you didn't include.